# How to avoid the overlap of divs?

Tags: html, css

i have created about three divs  one,two and three where  float left is given to div one and float
right is given to second div and no float is given to the third,the third div is overlapping with the
first and second divs

How  to avoid overlap of divs with each other

Comment: I think you can use flex or grid css to layout your div. [grid](https://learncssgrid.com/) & [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Please show us relevant code otherwise we are just guessing at an appropriate answer. For example, how are you sizing the divs and is the third div something that needs to be a div or could it be just text and are you wanting the text to flow around the first and second divs (ie do you really want float or would grid do?). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, if you have issue with floats, you need to apply `clear:both` to your third div

```css
#one {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

#two {
  float: right;
  width: 33.33%;
}

#three {
  clear: both;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">Div One</div>
<div id="two">Div Two</div>
<div id="three">Div Three</div>
```

**Approach two**: If you want three grids in same row, you can use css grid

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
  column-gap: 50px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also see https://ronnieroyston.com/tools/css-flexbox. For even more powerful 2 dimensional control see CSS Grid.

```css
div:nth-of-type(1){
  background:red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
div:nth-of-type(2){
  background:blue;
}
div:nth-of-type(3){
  background:green;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  gap: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
</main>
```